# Generete the worst case fot local insertion sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, pseudocode

Any idea of how can i generate and print the worst case for Local insetion sort?. This is my implementation of local insertion sort:

```
public class InsertionSort{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        int i;
        int array[] = {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10}; 
        System.out.println("Values Before the sort:\n");  

        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print( array[i]+"  ");
        System.out.println();

        insertion_srt(array, array.length);  
        System.out.print("Values after the sort:\n");  

        for(i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i]+"  ");

        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.println("PAUSE"); 
    }

    public static void insertion_srt(int array[], int n){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            int j = i;
            int B = array[i];
            while ((j > 0) && (array[j-1] > B)){
                array[j] = array[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            array[j] = B;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i modify it in order to generate the **worst case**?.

Comment: It will be much easier to tell what your code is doing if you can format it using any of the conventional styles.

Comment: In insertion sorting take the element form left assign value into a variable. Then compare the  value with  previous values. Put  value so that values must be lesser than the previous values. Then assign  next  value to a variable and follow the same steps relatively until the comparison not reached to end of array.

Comment: @winstonsmith It still would be much easier if you'd make the snippet you've presented readable instead of adding poetry to this unreadable wall of code.

Comment: The simplest worst case input is an array sorted in reverse order. The set of all worst case inputs consists of all arrays where each element is the smallest or second-smallest of the elements before it.

Comment: The code is very clear...

Comment: The code is clear because @BevynQ edited it (thanks!) to provide proper indentation.  Loop structures are rather difficult to read without proper indentation.  Also (and this is unrelated to the answer for you question), you may want to look into `Arrays.toString` with which you could simply `System.out.println( Arrays.toString( array ))` instead of iterating through the array every time you want to print it.

Answer (score 1):

An array sorted in descending order would be the worst case (or, for a generic implementation, the reverse of the order the sort would put it in).

To see this, consider how insertion sort works:

At any point, the input is split into two - sorted on the left, unsorted on the right:

```
sorted | unsorted
```

Initially the sorted part starts off empty, and then we repeatedly insert the left-most element of the unsorted part into it, shifting up the values to the right to make room for it.

Now the worst case for each insert will be when we have to insert it all the way on the left - we'll have to shift up all the other values to get it where it needs to be. When will this happen? When the element to be inserted is smaller than all the elements to the left.

So, the worst case is when each element is smaller than all elements to the left of it, and this is just the array in descending order.